# Does Lexus RX 400h/450h have electric power steering?

Tags: power-steering, part-identification, lexus, hybrid

I wonder whether both Lexus RX 400h and 450h have electric power steering (EPS) or classical old hydraulic power steering. Can anyone point confirm and point to a part number?

In case 400h has EPS is the electric motor located on the steering column or down on the steering rack? In case 400h has no EPS, does 450h already have it?

Comment: Which years are you talking about?

Comment: And are you considering "electric" to mean *electronic*. I've found evidence the 2014 RX450H has electronic steering, but I do not believe it is incorporated into the rack & pinion directly.

Comment: Well the 400h is RX Mk2 (2003-2008) and 450h is Mk3 (2008-2015). I dont have a particular exact car in mind I need general information. I mean electric in comparison to hydraulic/electric-hydralic.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like from 2006-2008 RX400h and 2010+ RX450h have electronic power steering (at least in the USA). The RX 400h has the motor as part of the rack assembly. The RX450h has the motor in the steering column assembly.

RX400h

44200-48133

RX450h

45250-0E081

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I am interested in RX 450h instead of GS 450h. Did you make a typo maybe and meant the RX 450h?

Comment: @Kozuch Sorry, my mistake. Fixed.